# Lasso Plugin won't work with D3 upgrade to V6

Tags: d3.js

I'm fairly new to D3 and I am trying to use d3.js & Lasso in order to allow users to select dots on a scatterplot. I've found an example of how to do this right here: http://bl.ocks.org/skokenes/511c5b658c405ad68941

This works perfectly fine in D3 with V5 but I have a requirement to upgrade to D3 V6 and the code breaks.

```
d3-lasso.js:819 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceEvent' of undefined
at SVGRectElement.dragmove (d3-lasso.js:819)
at nt.call (d3.min.js:2)
at Object.e [as mouse] (d3.min.js:2)
at p (d3.min.js:2)
at d3.min.js:2
```

Any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: As for your likely why, D3v6 made breaking changes in regard to events and event listeners - you'll likely either have to edit the source code for d3-lasso or wait until a new version of d3-lasso is released.

Comment: Yes that is true, I did change some code from d3.event.sourceEvent to event.sourceEvent and d3.mouse to d3.pointer. Still testing will post an update soon.

Comment: I have the same problem than you, did you succeed in porting d3-lasso to d3v6 ?

Comment: no I did not have much luck. Did try modifying the code but it caused other issues.

Answer (score 3):

-- 2023 solution for D3.v7

I rewrite the lasso function from scratch using the d3 drag event.
Below shows you an example of how to perform lasso selection on a scatter plot. The basic idea is to render a path when your cursor moves on the screen and determine which points are inside your polygon using an existing algorithm.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>d3-lasso</title>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #chart {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: wheat;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <svg id="chart">

        </svg>
    </div>

    <script>

        const data = [
            { x: -4, y: 14, id: 1 },
            { x: -26, y: -49, id: 2 },
            { x: 28, y: 11, id: 3 },
            { x: 0, y: -30, id: 4 },
            { x: 6.9, y: -63, id: 5 }
        ];
        let xScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d.x)))
            .range([50, 550]);
        let yScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d.y)))
            .range([50, 350]);

        const circles = d3
            .select("#chart")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("id", (d) => {
                return "dot-" + d.id;
            })
            .attr("cx", (d) => {
                return xScale(d.x);
            })
            .attr("cy", (d) => {
                return yScale(d.y);
            })
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("opacity", 0.5)
            .attr("fill", 'steelblue');

        // lasso selection based on the drag events
        let coords = [];
        const lineGenerator = d3.line();

        const pointInPolygon = function (point, vs) {
            // console.log(point, vs);
            // ray-casting algorithm based on
            // https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html/pnpoly.html

            var x = point[0],
                y = point[1];

            var inside = false;
            for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
                var xi = vs[i][0],
                    yi = vs[i][1];
                var xj = vs[j][0],
                    yj = vs[j][1];

                var intersect =
                    yi > y != yj > y &&
                    x < ((xj - xi) * (y - yi)) / (yj - yi) + xi;
                if (intersect) inside = !inside;
            }

            return inside;
        };

        function drawPath() {
            d3.select("#lasso")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", 2)
                .style("fill", "#00000054")
                .attr("d", lineGenerator(coords));
        }

        function dragStart() {
            coords = [];
            circles.attr("fill", "steelblue");
            d3.select("#lasso").remove();
            d3.select("#chart")
                .append("path")
                .attr("id", "lasso");
        }

        function dragMove(event) {
            let mouseX = event.sourceEvent.offsetX;
            let mouseY = event.sourceEvent.offsetY;
            coords.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
            drawPath();
        }

        function dragEnd() {
            let selectedDots = [];
            circles.each((d, i) => {
                let point = [
                    xScale(d.x),
                    yScale(d.y),
                ];
                if (pointInPolygon(point, coords)) {
                    d3.select("#dot-" + d.id).attr("fill", "red");
                    selectedDots.push(d.id);
                }
            });
            console.log(`select: ${selectedDots}`);
        }

        const drag = d3
            .drag()
            .on("start", dragStart)
            .on("drag", dragMove)
            .on("end", dragEnd);

        d3.select("#chart").call(drag);


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```