# How should I go about making a scatterplot d3 lasso component in react?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am very new to react and I would like to try implementing a scatterplot in my React web app but I'm not really sure how to get started on that. I want to be able to display a scatterplot and I would like the user to be able to interact with the scatterplot and be able to select a few points on it using a lasso. I know there is a package that I should be using called d3-lasso however I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use it. I have found some JS code on how to implement such a lasso, however, I'm not sure how I would go implementing it in my app. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have looked at a few pieces of code ([here](https://gist.github.com/skokenes/511c5b658c405ad68941) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432092/implementation-of-d3-lasso-in-react)) I've found online and have found trouble implementing them into my app. I am really new to react and JS so I'm not sure how I would really work them into a component.